# PostgreSQL restore function error in database

Tags: postgresql, macos, importerror, restore

I am trying to restore a database from a computer to the system using the restore function (the document is in Tar format). When I load the table, the message “restore job created” appears, but the message “successfully completed” does not appear. The problem is that data does not appear in the list of tables (even after refresh). I am also unable to IMPORT the data from the file.

When I try to do similar functions on Windows - everything works, on Macos - no, what could be the problem?

In System preferences, I have already given the PostgreSQL 9.6 access rights to the data of the desktop and individual folders, it did not help.

My steps are the following:

1. create database Supermarkt DB
2. Supermarkt DB - restore - custom or tar format - filename - select - all files - /Users/thenameofmyaccount/Desktop/SQL/Code/data/Supermart_DB_new/ (tar format) - Select - push the button Restore
3. 'restore job created' sign appears
4. Database - refresh - Schemas - Public - Tables (and there are nothing, new tables from the source file do not appear)

Comment: This is going to need more information. First, there is no restore function in Postgres so are you talking about the ```pg_restore``` program? If so how was the database dumped using ```pg_dump```(complete command line) and how was it restored with ```pg_restore```(complete command line). If you are not using ```pg_restore```, what are you using and how? How are you doing the data import and what are the errors?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for your prompt reply. My steps are the following: 1) create database Supermarkt DB 2) Supermarkt DB - restore - custom or tar format - filename - select - all files - /Users/thenameofmyaccount/Desktop/SQL/Code/data/Supermart_DB_new/ (tar format) - Select - push the button Restore 3) 'restore job created' sign appears 4) Database - refresh - Schemas - Public - Tables (and there are nothing, new tables from the source file do not appear).

Comment: Added information in comment to question to make it easier to follow. What program are you doing this in?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: That is the server you are working with. I'm asking about the program that you are doing steps 1-4 in? Have you looked in the Postgres log to see what is happening?